# Using Avro throws a AvroRuntimeException Malformed data

Tags: clojure, avro

I have the following code:

```
(defn parse-schema
  "Returns an Avro schema"
  ^Schema$RecordSchema [^String schema-file]
  (let [schema (File. schema-file)]
    (.parse (Schema$Parser.) schema-file)))

(defn get-reader
  "Returns a DatumReader"
  ^SpecificDatumReader [^Schema$RecordSchema schema]
  (SpecificDatumReader. schema))

(defn byte-to-object
  "Returns an object from a byte[]"
  [reader message]
  (let [ decoder (.binaryDecoder (DecoderFactory/get) message nil) ]
    (.read reader nil decoder)))
```

Using the code in repl:

```
plugflow.main=> (avro/parse-schema "schema/test.avsc")
#object[org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema 0x6e896dd7 "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"test\",\"namespace\":\"com.streambright.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"user_name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"User name of any user\"}],\"doc:\":\"Nothing to see here...\"}"]
plugflow.main=> (def record-schema (avro/parse-schema "schema/test.avsc"))
#'plugflow.main/record-schema
plugflow.main=> (avro/get-reader record-schema)
#object[org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader 0x56b1cac6 "org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader@56b1cac6"]
plugflow.main=> (def avro-reader (avro/get-reader record-schema))
#'plugflow.main/avro-reader
plugflow.main=> (import '[java.nio.file Files Paths Path])
java.nio.file.Path
plugflow.main=> (import '[java.net URI])
java.net.URI
plugflow.main=> (def byte-arr (Files/readAllBytes (Paths/get (URI. "file:///data/test.avro"))))
#'plugflow.main/byte-arr
plugflow.main=> (avro/byte-to-object avro-reader byte-arr))
AvroRuntimeException Malformed data. Length is negative: -40  org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadBytes (BinaryDecoder.java:336)
```

Using Avro CLI:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar tojson data/test.avro
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
{"user_name":"tibi"}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there are two set of Avro classes one for reading and writing Avro files and one for reading and writing Avro encoded messages. In case of using the avro-cli it writes a proper Avro file that has the schema included in it. When I was trying to read the file with the functions designed for dealing with the Avro encoded messages it obviously failed.

The right way of writing a single Avro message without the schema (in case you would like to use it in unit tests or integration test)

```
    Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse("{\n  \"type\": \"record\",\n  \"name\": \"User\",\n  \"namespace\": \"com.streambright\",\n  \"fields\": [{\n    \"name\": \"user_name\",\n    \"type\": \"string\",\n    \"doc\": \"User name of the user\"\n  }, {\n    \"name\": \"age\",\n    \"type\": \"int\",\n    \"doc\": \"Age of the user\"\n  }, {\n    \"name\": \"weight\",\n    \"type\": \"float\",\n    \"doc\": \"Weight of the user\"\n  }, {\n    \"name\": \"address\",\n    \"type\": {\n      \"type\": \"record\",\n      \"name\": \"Address\",\n      \"fields\": [{\n        \"name\": \"street_address\",\n        \"type\": \"string\"\n      }, {\n        \"name\": \"city\",\n        \"type\": \"string\"\n      }]\n    }\n  }],\n  \"doc:\": \"Nothing to see here...\"\n}");
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserName("Tibi Kovacs");
    user.setAge(25);
    user.setWeight(((float) 32.12));
    user.setAddress(new Address("FoxiMaxi St","Budapest"));
    SpecificDatumWriter<User> avroEventWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<User>(schema);
    EncoderFactory avroEncoderFactory = EncoderFactory.get();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder = avroEncoderFactory.binaryEncoder(stream, null);
    avroEventWriter.write(user, binaryEncoder);
    binaryEncoder.flush();
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
    byte[] m = stream.toByteArray();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/full/path/data/test3.java.avro");
    fos.write(m);
    fos.close();
```